# Error: 'module' object has no attribute 'readNet' How can I fix this error?

Tags: python, object, detection, yolo

I am trying to follow the same steps in the code below to learn how I can make object detection using Yolo https://www.arunponnusamy.com/yolo-object-detection-openCV-python.html. I am using `Python 2.7`. After I run this part of the code, I have received this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'readNet'
```

I need really your help to fix this error

```
import cv2
import argparse
import numpy as np

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()

ap.add_argument('-i', '--image', required=False,default='D:/darknet/data/dog.jpg',help = 'path to input image')

ap.add_argument('-c', '--config',required=False,default='D:/darknet/cfg/yolov3.cfg',help = 'path to yolo config file')

ap.add_argument('-w', '--weights', required=False,default='D:/darknet/yolov3.weights',
                 help = 'path to yolo pre-trained weights')

ap.add_argument('-cl', '--classes', required=False,default='D:/darknet/yolov3.txt',
                help = 'path to text file containing class names')

args = ap.parse_args()

image = cv2.imread(args.image)

Width = image.shape[1]

Height = image.shape[0]

scale = 0.00392

classes = None

with open(args.classes, 'r') as f:
    classes = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

COLORS = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(len(classes), 3))

net = cv2.dnn.readNet(args.weights, args.config)

blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, scale, (416,416), (0,0,0), True,crop=False)

net.setInput(blob)
```

Comment: What version of OpenCV (cv2) are you using? Could you provide a full stack trace?

Comment: On the site you linked, there are dependencies listed that says that it will require Python 3. In your question you've written that you're using Python 2.7. I am not familiar with all the packages used in the code, but I suspect that could be the culprit.

Comment: from this site "https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/" I downloaded this package for opencv (cv2): opencv_python‑2.4.13.5‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl

Comment: I downloaded python 3.5 but when I downloaded "opencv_python‑3.4.3‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl" from the same link above, and take the folder of opencv and put it in set_packages for Python 3.5 .. It doesn't work because of this I used python 2.7

Comment: Tredzko, Did I answer your question?

Comment: I need to your help